# C programming nesting switch in if-else does not work. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: c

This code compiles and takes the input. But then it does not show the result. I looked through but dont see any error.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int a,b;
  char c;
  int res=0;
  scanf("%d %c %d",&a,&c,&b);
  //printf("%d %c %d",a,c,b);
  if(c!='+' || c!='-' || c!='*' || c!='/' ){
    return NAN;
  }
  else{

    switch(c){
      case '+':
        res=a+b;
        break;
      case '-': 
        res=a-b;
        break;            
      case '*':
        res=(a)*(b);
        break;

      case '/':
        res= a/b;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  printf("result is %d\n",res);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `if(c!='+' || c!='-' || c!='*' || c!='/' ){` : `||` should be `&&`

Comment: That's not the entire source file. You're missing several `#include` directives. What is `NAN`, and why is it a sensible value to return from `main`? And most important, what exactly does "it does not show the result" mean? Don't tell us what it doesn't do; tell us what it does.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I guess that should be the answer.

Comment: replace `!=` with `==` in the `if` clause

Comment: @BLUEPIXY wowwwwww, that's just solved it. It was a huge logical mistake. What I had in my mind is except the +,-,*,/ operations everything else should return false. but that was completely wrong thinking. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `else` is unnecessary; `return` causes the function to return.

Comment: what input do you feed and what output do you get? Sorry, but accept a downvote.  Don't say something does not work, say exactly what it does.  What input have you fed to the program can also help in determining why it fails.  It seems you are trying to implement some kind of calculator, but calculators can fail in many ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement is wrong. It will be always true if you enter one of the 4 operators (or every other char.. )
Use AND operator ( && ) instead of OR ( ||).

```
if(c!='+' && c!='-' && c!='*' && c!='/' ){
    return NAN;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Bluepixy pointed out, your primary problem was the `||` verses `&&`. However, your `return (..)` is also incorrect. It should be `exit` or drop the parens:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int a,b;
    char c;
    int res=0;

    scanf("%d %c %d",&a,&c,&b);

    if(c!='+' && c!='-' && c!='*' && c!='/' )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case '+':
                res=a+b;
                break;
            case '-': 
                res=a-b;
                break;            
            case '*':
                res=(a)*(b);
                break;

            case '/':
                res= a/b;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("result is %d\n",res);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/calc_simple
10 + 10
result is 20
```

Comment: What's your problem with the parens after `return`? They're unnecessary, sure; but they're not going to cause incorrect results, and the question is about incorrect results.

Comment: Agreed, I just noted them. Perhaps not worth mentioning.

Comment: Why do you have brackets here:`res=(a)*(b);`?